# SQL Query to to make fromDate and toDate?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create query from two tables, say Employee and Appraisal. Both of these tables have one to many relationship. Appraisal table has record of employee when an employee joining, rejoining or exit depending on the AppraisalType column.

```
select dbo.Employee.EmployeeID
      ,dbo.Employee.FullName
      ,dbo.Employee.CostCenterID
      ,ea.AppraisalDate as fromDate
      ,
       (select case
                   when exists
                               (select 1
                                from
                                     EmployeeAppraisal as EA2
                                where EA2.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID
                                      and EA2.AppraisalType = 'Exit'
                                having min(EA2.AppraisalDate) > EA.AppraisalDate
                               )
                       then
                            (select min(AppraisalDate)
                             from
                                  EmployeeAppraisal as EA2
                             where EA2.EmployeeID = EA.EmployeeID
                                   and EA2.AppraisalType = 'Exit'
                             having min(EA2.AppraisalDate) > EA.AppraisalDate
                            )
                   else getdate()
               end
       ) as ToDate
      ,0 as MonthDiff
      ,dbo.Employee.IsActive
from
     dbo.Employee
    join EmployeeAppraisal as EA
        on Employee.EmployeeID = EA.EmployeeID
where EA.AppraisalType = 'Re-Joining'
      and Employee.EmployeeId = 1253;
```

And this gives following resultset. It is giving same incorrect toDate for all rows

[image]

While Actual data is, please note that Rejoining date should be fromDate and Exit should be toDate. Any help is appreciated

[image]  .

Comment: Please add the source data as a `create table ... insert into ...` script so we can actually use it in helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved rather easily with an `apply`.  These are different to `join`s in that they let you reference the other tables in your query.  In this case I am filtering the table in the `apply` to only hold `Exit` records where the `AppraisalDate` is after the `Re-Joining` date of the specific row, then selecting the most recent one, with the `top 1` and `order by`:

```
declare @e table(EmployeeID int);
insert into @e values(1253);

declare @a table(EmployeeID int,AppraisalDate datetime,AppraisalType nvarchar(10));
insert into @a values
 (1253,'20140101','Exit')
,(1253,'20140601','Re-Joining')
,(1253,'20150101','Exit')
,(1253,'20150601','Re-Joining')
,(1253,'20160101','Exit')
,(1253,'20160601','Re-Joining')
,(1253,'20170101','Exit')
,(1253,'20170601','Re-Joining')
,(1253,'20180101','Exit');


select e.EmployeeID
    ,f.AppraisalDate as FromDate
    ,t.AppraisalDate as ToDate
from @e e
    join @a f
        on e.EmployeeID = f.EmployeeID
            and f.AppraisalType = 'Re-Joining'
    outer apply (select top 1 AppraisalDate
                    from @a tt
                    where tt.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
                        and tt.AppraisalDate > f.AppraisalDate
                        and tt.AppraisalType = 'Exit'
                    order by tt.AppraisalDate
                ) t;
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| EmployeeID |        FromDate         |         ToDate          |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|       1253 | 2014-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
|       1253 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
|       1253 | 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
|       1253 | 2017-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Outstanding solution. Thanks @iamdave you saved my day :)